# || operator not setting default when null

Tags: javascript

I am running this line:

```
var good = data["good"] || false;
```

where `data` comes from the `success` method in a jquery ajax request.

But, what I thought that this would do is default `good` to `false` if `data["good"]` is null, but it is not.

Chrome is throwing this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'good' of null
```

and since it is `null`, shouldn't `good` then be set to `false`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not that `data["good"]` is `null`, but that `data` itself is `null`.

Your code as is would be fine if `data` always has a value, but may not have property `good`. But unfortunately the JavaScript engine doesn't check if *everything* in a statement is undefined or null, i.e. it won't test `data`, and then test `data["good"]` and so on.

You need to test if `data` has at least some sort of value first, that is, it is "truthy".

### Fix 1

You can lay it out clearly like so:

```
var good = false;
if(data && data["good"]) {
    good = data["good"];
}
```

### Fix 2

Or a neat shortcut is to use the fact that `&&` and `||` will return the first "truthy" *value* found - it does not have to be a boolean:

```
var good = (data && data["good"]) || false;
```

The [jquery tutorial on Operators](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/operators/#logical-operators) has a good explanation of what is returned from the `&&` and `||` operators.

```js
// has a value - sets to "foo"
var data1 = { good: 'foo' };
var good1 = (data1 && data1["good"]) || false;
document.write("<div>" + good1 + "</div>");

// data is null - sets to false
var data2 = null;
var good2 = (data2 && data2["good"]) || false;
document.write("<div>" + good2 + "</div>");

// data["good"] doesn't exist - sets to false
var data3 = { bad: 'hello' };
var good3 = (data3 && data3["good"]) || false;
document.write("<div>" + good3 + "</div>");
```

### Falsy Gotchas!

The other thing to be careful of is that some values you would want to store in your variable may evaluate to false, so you might incorrectly end up with `good = false`. This depends on what you expect to be inside `data["good"]`.

This will occur for the following, again from [the jquery site](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/conditional-code/#truthy-and-falsy-things):

- `false` - boolean false value
- `""` - Empty strings
- `NaN` - "not-a-number"
- null - null values
- `undefined` - undefined values (i.e. if data doesn't have property "good")
- `0` - the number zero.

If you think this could be the case, you may need to be more specific in your checks:

```js
var data = { good: 0 };

// 0 is falsy, so incorrectly sets to false
var good = (data && data["good"]) || false;
document.write("<div>" + good + "</div>");

// check the actual type and value - correctly set to 0
var good2 = (data && (typeof data["good"] != "undefined") && data["good"] != null)
    ? data["good"] : false;
document.write("<div>" + good2 + "</div>");
```

Comment: I was about to write the same, but it is not correct. `good` will not have value of data[good] in any case - OP didnt mention data[good] will contain only boolean.

Comment: Ohh... Okay, I thought that it checked everything

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I can't imagine one-liner, which will check if `data` is not null and if so, put `data[good]` into variable.

You must first of all, get rid of `Exception`.
I would rather do:

```
var good = false;
if(data){
    good = data["good"] || false;
}
```